# User would like to export only Crystal Reports invoices that only take up one page. Then print out invoices that take up two pages

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, business-objects

I developed an invoice using Crystal Reports.   Invoice sometimes takes up two pages.  User would like to be able to choose to print only one page invoices or only the invoices that take up two pages.  That way the user can send invoices that take up multiple pages in one file, and then single page invoices in another file to the vendor.

Thanks in advance.

Best,
Carl

Comment: Is there something consistent that forces a second page such as item count? If so, you could you create two versions of the report; one with the item count less than that key value and the other greater than or equal to that key value.

Answer (score 0):

One of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports tools listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched) provides a solution for this scenario. In a single pass, it can generate for each invoice in the report a separate PDF file and embed in the name of the pdf the number of pages it contains.  This then allows you to use the file names to control which files get printed.

Here is an image showing how the resulting files can be sorted by number of pages:
[image: PDF Split to Multiple Files with Number of Pages in File Name]